# Solr queries stored within Solr field

Tags: solr

I have a set of keywords defined by client requirements stored in a SOLR field. I also have a never ending stream of sentences entering the system.

By using the sentence as the query against the keywords I am able to find those sentences that match the keywords. This is working well and I am pleased. What I have essentially done is reverse the way in which SOLR is normally used by storing the query in Solr and passing the text in as the query.

Now I would like to be able to extend the idea of having just a keyword in a field to having a more fully formed SOLR query in a field. Doing so would allow proximity searching etc. But, of course, this is where life becomes awkward. Placing SOLR query operators into a field will not work as they need to be escaped.

Does anyone know if it might be possible to use the SOLR "query" function or perhaps write a java class that would enable such functionality? Or is the idea blowing just a bit too much against the SOLR winds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES has percolate for this - for Solr you'll usually index the document as a single document in a memory based core / index and then run the queries against that (which is what ES at least used to do internally, IIRC).

Comment: I have discovered the percolate functionality in es and have mimicked it using a memory based core. It didn't take too much to implement just a bit more knowledge of how lucene works. The additional cpu load is < 2% using this technique si feel it is fine for the time being, at least until SOLR supports it out if the box.

Comment: I used the following tutorial to implement my code. Pretty much worked first time. [DIY Percolator - SlideShare](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=eOGhVcvXKIqb0gTE0K0o&url=http://www.slideshare.net/jdhok/diy-percolator&ved=0CCEQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNECTaUDO2_fmUhS8clbWb1CXmz7ng)

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the percolate api with ElasticSearch. It would sure be easier using this api than having to write your own in Solr.